# oracle rest data services save sent file to a directory

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Android app which is sending images to ORDS using resp api and then images are stored into a table.

Is there any way I can save images to a server directory and save a link to a file  instead of saving images a database table?

Anyone has any example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use utl_file to write them to a directory on the server, but why not serve them up using the database, if they're already there?